# Is it possible to construct automation framework with Selenium+docker, without selenium grid but with Pytest Internal parallel execution system?

Tags: docker, selenium, webautomation, pytest-xdist

Currently, I have an automation framework that consists of the following stack:

- Python
- Pytest Framework (and pytest-xdist parallel mechanized)
- Selenium
- Allure report system
- Jenkins

I'm going to add a docker containerization system as well, to run tests using it on a windows server.

I'm running my tests using pytest's internal parallel run (pytest-xdist) functionality using 'workers'
the run command looks like this:

```
os.system("pytest -v -s --alluredir="'C:\AllureReports\Data'" --html=report.html --developer=dmitriy --timeout=60 --self-contained-html --dist=loadfile -n=3 -m=regression")
```

As you can see '-n=3' is the number of 'nodes' that the suite will be executed. In other words, the regression suite will run in a parallel run of 3 nodes.

Can you tell me if it is possible to avoid using Selenium-Grid mechanized, and use this pytest's internal parallel run system instead -> **pytest-xdist**, and how?

Will appreciate relevant technical articles or explanations of how it can be done.

I have gone over this question - [pytest-xdist vs selenium hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42983682/using-docker-with-selenium-and-pytest-to-run-parallel-tests)
but got only a really overview impression which is not enough